# Is there no way to remove grease pencil outline problem?

Tags: grease-pencil

[image]

I converted a cube to a grease pencil.

[image]

But if I zoom in the grease pencil, it's outline is damaged by the 'white' face.

[image]

I want it to look like a neat outline.

Is there a good way?